# Is it possible to install postgres second time?

Tags: postgresql, debian

So right now due to ERP system that I use in company I have heavily modified version 11 of Postgresql.
Now I need to have a clean version of Postgresql installed? Is that somehow possible to install Postgresql twice?

Comment: I suggest you to use docker images to do so and keep several isolated versions of your tools.

Comment: @mcanzerini I have it created on docker. Now is a thing how to connect to this database using for example PgAdmin?

Comment: I'm sure you'll find a response here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540711/docker-postgres-pgadmin-local-connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can install the new version in another directory and start new postgresql in another port 5432 (example: 5433)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible ([see this answer also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6456959/17773667)), but settings will slightly be different depending on OS that you use. Postgres uses by default port 5432 but you can change this, so even if you need both of versions to run at the same time it is not a problem. You just need to set a correct port. So simply put you can do that but need to change config file of one of the versions.